# How to join two columns of float to singe column in int format?

Tags: pandas

I have two columns which are in float type and i want to join those two columns with '-' and resultant column should be in int format.

Comment: column1 --- [10 , 20.0 , 30.0, 45.5, null , 36.3 ]
column2 --- [20.0, 10, 30.5, 20, null , 20 ]
resultant --- [10 - 20, 20 - 10, 30 - 30, 45 - 20, null, 36 - 20]

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is remove missing values by `dropna`, convert to integers and to strings for possible join together:

```
a= [10 , 20.0 , 30.0, 45.5, np.nan , 36.3 ] 
b = [20.0, 10, 30.5, 20, np.nan , 20 ]
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':a, 'col2':b})

s1 = df['col1'].dropna().astype('int').astype(str)
s2 = df['col1'].dropna().astype('int').astype(str)

s1 = df.loc[df['col1'].notna(), 'col1'].astype('int').astype(str)
s2 = df.loc[df['col2'].notna(), 'col2'].astype('int').astype(str)
```

---

```
df['res1'] = s1.str.cat(s2, sep=' - ')
```

Alternative:

```
df['res2'] = s1 + ' - ' + s2
```

```
print (df)
   col1  col2     res1     res2
0  10.0  20.0  10 - 20  10 - 20
1  20.0  10.0  20 - 10  20 - 10
2  30.0  30.5  30 - 30  30 - 30
3  45.5  20.0  45 - 20  45 - 20
4   NaN   NaN      NaN      NaN
5  36.3  20.0  36 - 20  36 - 20
```

Comment: I got error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'notna'

Comment: @Sunil - because ald pandas version, change `notna()` to `notnull()`.